# onConfigurationChanged not called for second time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I am using the following code to change my activity orientation while user rotates the device. This works fine for first time, but not called again. Please correct me.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);            
        Log.d("ACTIVITY","CHANGING ORIENTATION"); //No i18n
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ORIENTATION CHANGED TO PORTRAIT"); // No I18N
            setRequestedOrientation(Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ORIENTATION CHANGED TO LANDSCAPE"); // No I18N
            setRequestedOrientation(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("ACTIVITY","ON RESTORE INSTANCESTATE");   //No i18n
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d("ACTIVITY","ON SAVE INSTANCESTATE");  //No i18n
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After you use `setRequestedOrientation(...);` you no longer have the privilege of getting rotation notifications.
If you want to perform special actions when rotations occur, you may want to use `OrientationEventListener`

**EDIT:**
CAUTION: this code takes portrait as 80-90 deg and >= 320, this can be changed.
You may also need to run setRequestedOrientation on UI thread if this piece of code isn't running there already.

You should do something like this:

```
mOrientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {

@Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int rotation) {
        boolean changed = false;

        if (((rotation >= 0) && (rotation <= 80)) || (rotation >= 320)) {
                        setRequestedOrientation(Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else {
                        setRequestedOrientation(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }
};
mOrientationListener.enable();
```

Comment: Finally! I was looking for a similar solution for hours